# Finding the $z$ coordinate of center of mass for $C:= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq z \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**The Problem**

> Let $C$ be the cone
> $$C:= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq z \leq 1$$
> Assume that $C$ has a constant mass density and find the z coordinate of the center of mass.

**The work I have done:**

\begin{align*}
M_{xy}&=\iint_{R}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{1} z \,\delta \,dx \,dy \,dx\\
&=\iint_{R} \delta \,\frac{z^2}{2} \Bigg|_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{1} \,dy \,dx\\
&=\iint_{R} \delta \,\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2} \Big) \,dy \,dx
\end{align*}

Switching to polar coordinates now and pulling out the constants:
\begin{align*}
&=\frac{\delta}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} \big(r-r^3 \big) \,dr \,d\theta\\
&=\frac{\delta}{2} (\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{\pi}{4}\,\delta\,.\\
\\
M&=\iint_{R}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{1} \,\delta \,dx \,dy \,dx\\
&=\iint_{R} \delta (1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \,dy \,dx
\end{align*}

Switching again to polar:
\begin{align*}
&=\delta \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (1-r) \,r \,dr \,d\theta\\
&=\delta \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{6} d\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\delta
\end{align*}
Therefore:

$$\bar{z}=\frac{M_{xy}}{M} = \frac{\pi\delta}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{\pi\delta}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Is my answer correct?

Edit: I also know that I could have switched to cylindrical from the beginning. If I did, would the integral I need to evaluate be $$M=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r}^{1} \,r \,dz \,dr\,d\theta$$

and

$$M_{xy}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{r}^{1} \,rz \,dz \,dr\,d\theta\,?$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a cone of base radius $1$, and height $1$.  The center of mass formula is

$ \overline{z} = \displaystyle \dfrac{ \iiint z dV } {\iiint dV} $

The numerator is

$ \displaystyle \iiint z dV = \int_{z=0}^1 (2 \pi z^3)dz = \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

The denominator is

$ \displaystyle \iiint z dV = \int_{z=0}^1 (2 \pi z^2)dz = \dfrac{2\pi}{3} $

Hence,

$ \overline{z} = \dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{2} }{ \dfrac{ 2}{3}} = \dfrac{3}{4} $

Answer (score 0):

The cylindrical integral is slightly off.

You are computing the center of mass for a Cone of height 1 and base radius 1. So the cylindrical integral will be
$$
M=\int_{0}^{1}\,dz\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{z} \,r  \,dr\,
$$
You could integrate each $z$ plane by eye.
$$
M=\int_{0}^{1}\,dz \pi z^2 =\frac 13\pi\\
M_z=\int_{0}^{1}\,dz \pi z^2 z=\frac 14\pi
$$
$$
\bar z = M_z / M=3/4
$$

Comment: hm I think in your last step you meant to write 3/4 instead of 4/3 right? Because I got the same exact values for $M$ and $M_z$ with the cylindrical coordinates that I used

Comment: also is it correct for the original way I did it?

Comment: Thanks for comment! Your original answer is correct too~